# Setting the default rvm gemset with Ansible?

Tags: rvm, ansible, osx-elcapitan, ubuntu-16.04

Using: Mac OS X 10.11.5, ansible 2.0.1.0, Python 2.7.11. Ubuntu Xenial LTS (Vagrant 1.8.1 with VirtualBox Version 5.0.16 r105871) as a remote.

I'm trying to set a new gemset as the default using Ansible like this:

```
    ---
    # file: roles/ruby-gemset/tasks/main.yml

    - name: RVM | check if the bwv gemset needs to be set default.
      command: rvm list gemsets
      register: gemset_needs_an_update
      environment:
        PATH: "{{ rvm_path }}:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
        GEM_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}"
        GEM_PATH: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@global"
      changed_when: gemset_needs_an_update.stdout.find('=> ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv') == -1

    - name: RVM | Create and use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv.
      command: "rvm use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv --create"
      environment:
        PATH: "{{ rvm_path }}:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
        GEM_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv"
        GEM_PATH: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@global"
      when: gemset_needs_an_update.stdout.find('=> ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv') == -1

    - name: RVM | Use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv gemset as default.
      command: "rvm use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv --default"
      environment:
        PATH: "{{ rvm_path }}:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"
        GEM_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv"
        GEM_PATH: "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@global"
      when: gemset_needs_an_update.stdout.find('=> ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv') == -1
```

The idea is to write an Ansible playbook that would make an usable ruby gemset installation to a remote Ubuntu server. But for some reason the default isn't changed at all. Instead this happens over and over again:

```
    TASK [ruby-gemset : RVM | check if the bwv gemset needs to be set default.] ****
    changed: [xenial64]

    TASK [ruby-gemset : RVM | Create and use ruby-2.3.1@bwv.] **********************
    changed: [xenial64]

    TASK [ruby-gemset : RVM | Use ruby-2.3.1@bwv gemset as default.] ***************
    changed: [xenial64]
```

Could it be done using Ansible somehow to the remote server? I realize that those environment lines help only the command to pass without failures, but do pretty much nothing now.

Comment: rvm uses the current environment heavily, which is not modifiable from commands you run unfortunately. Do you want to change the gemset for the user that calls this playbook, or only for some steps done later in the playbook?

Comment: I'm trying to do it for the user, as a permanent installation.

Answer (score 0):

At least this seems to work:

```
    ---
    # file: roles/ruby-gemset/tasks/main.yml

    - name: RVM | check if the bwv gemset needs to be set default.
      become_user: ubuntu
      command: bash -lc "rvm list gemsets"
      register: gemset_needs_an_update
      changed_when: gemset_needs_an_update.stdout.find('=> ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv') == -1

    - name: RVM | Create and use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv.
      become_user: ubuntu
      command: bash -lc "rvm use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv --create"
      when: gemset_needs_an_update.stdout.find('=> ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv') == -1

    - name: RVM | Use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv gemset as default.
      become_user: ubuntu
      command: bash -lc "rvm use ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv --default"
      when: gemset_needs_an_update.stdout.find('=> ruby-{{ ruby_version }}@bwv') == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the use of the `[rvm do set][1]` commands to help in getting around the minimal shell environments spawned by Ansible.

```
- name: Set Default Gem Set
  shell: "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm {{ use_ruby_version}} do rvm use {{ rvm_default }} --default"
  args:
    chdir: "/home/{{ user_name }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ user_name }}"
  tags:
    - default_gemset
```

Ansible Vars:

```
  use_ruby_version: ruby-2.2.5
  current_gemset: foo
  rvm_default: "{{ use_ruby_version }}@{{ current_gemset }}"
```

Running Ansible 2.1
        Centos 7/bash